# React Stopwatch timer not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

Need a React Timer Stopwatch that starts from `00:00:00` i.e., (hh:mm:ss) that estimates the time taken to finish a quiz, tried various things storing things in state.

Something similar to this :

[image]

But, `setState` Makes the app crash.

The Logic :

```
var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0, t;

state = { clock : '' };

componentDidMount()
{
  timer();
}

 add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }


    time = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    this.setState({ clock : time });

    timer();
}

timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}

/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```

The View :

```
</div>
  {this.state.clock}
<div>
```

Any way how to create a Stopwatch with start and stop option in react?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: can you add the error for the crash? Also, i would add {clock: '00:00:00'} as initial state in componentDidMount function. One more thing, you should define initial state in `constructor(props) { super(props); state = { clock:  '00:00:00'} ;`, not outside of the react class.

Comment: try this? https://wsvincent.com/react-stopwatch/

Comment: In learning the new React hooks API I made a stopwatch... here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/p58qny7y07

Comment: It looks inefficient to call `setState` every second as it re-renders the component. Why not just update local variables